# What laws are concerned about this negative example?

Tags: python-3.x, range

Find and fix an error in a for loop with range() function.

```
# This function should count down by -2 from 11 to 1, so that it only
# prints odd numbers. 

# This range(11, -2) tells the for loop to start at 11 and end at index
# position -2 (which corresponds to the numeric value of -1). Since the
# third incremental or decremental value is missing, the loop will 
# increment by the default of +1 instead of the intended -2 decrement.
# Starting at index position 11 and incrementing by +1 will end the loop 
# automatically, because the index is not counting down towards -2 as 
# the end of the range. 

# To fix this problem, the range() needs three parameters:
# First parameter should be the starting index position of 11.
# Second parameter should be the ending index position of 0 (value 1).
# Third parameter should be decrementing by -2.
# So, the range should be configured as range(11, 0, -2).

# Fix this loop with the corrected range parameters and click Run.
for n in range(11, -2):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        print(n, end=" ")

# Should print: 11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 once the problem is fixed.
```

Sure I know how to correct this:

```
for n in range(11, 0,-2):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        print(n, end=" ")
```

BUT I just cannot figure out why the initial code would not print out anything......
What laws are concerned about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) says:

> ##### class range(start, stop[, step])
>
> If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1

From this, we can infer that in `range(11, -2)`, the start argument is 11, the stop argument is -2, and the step argument is (positive) 1.

It continues:

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.

> ***A range object will be empty if `r[0]` does not meet the value constraint***

In other words, because start + step (11 + 1) is greater than stop (-2), the range object is empty.

I don't know which "laws" you were looking for, but perhaps the value constraint was what you were looking for?

Here is the relevant source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e36ca63f9f5e0399efe13a80499cef290314c2a/Objects/rangeobject.c#L270C1-L270C1